# How can I "unformat" a system?

Tags: windows-7, data-recovery, formatting

I have a system from work that I ended up formatting with a new OS. I was to install the OS in the D drive but ended up installing the OS in C. All my data and the monitoring softwares that my company had installed are gone.

As it stands, I might get into serious trouble if the company founds out so I wanted to take my system to how it was before, i.e, with the previous installation of Windows.

Is it possible to accomplish?

Comment: No. By reinstalling the OS you've ruined any chances of recovering data. Tell your companies IT department and have it redone properly, dealing with any acceptable use policy you violated.

Comment: Technically speaking, you have not ruined any chances, but any recovery you will perform will miss some stuff. Of course you would not get back the OS working as before, but you might recover the documents and stuff like that.